# How to get the percentages of a variable for each subgroups?

Tags: r

I'am using the esoph dataset that can be found in base R. It's a dataset that shows if there is a correlation between age, alcohol consumption and tobacco consumption and the probability of contracting esophageal cancer.

I have a barplot that shows the average number of oesophageal cancer ('ncases' variable) for each groups of tobacco consumption ('tobgp' variable, 4 groups in total from: 0-9g/day to 30+):

```
X = subset(esoph, select = c("tobgp", "ncases"))
heights=tapply(X$ncases, X$tobgp, mean)
barplot(heights, main = "Mean number of cases by tobacco consumption", 
        names.arg = c("0-9", "10-19", "20-29", "30+"),
        xlab="Daily tobacco consumption (grams)", ylab = "Number of cases")
```

I'm interested in knowing for each groups, what is the percentage of ncases ? I tried this:

```
tobgp9_data <- esoph[which(esoph[,"tobgp"] == "0-9g/day"),]
tobgp9_noZero <- tobgp9_data[which(tobgp9_data[, "ncases"] > 0 ),]
sum (tobgp9_noZero$ncases)

tobgp19_data <- esoph[which(esoph[,"tobgp"] == "10-19"),]
tobgp19_noZero <- tobgp19_data[which(tobgp19_data[, "ncases"] > 0 ),]
sum (tobgp19_noZero$ncases)

tobgp29_data <- esoph[which(esoph[,"tobgp"] == "20-29"),]
tobgp29_noZero <- tobgp29_data[which(tobgp29_data[, "ncases"] > 0 ),]
sum (tobgp29_noZero$ncases)

tobgp30_data <- esoph[which(esoph[,"tobgp"] == "30+"),]
tobgp30_noZero <- tobgp30_data[which(tobgp30_data[, "ncases"] > 0 ),]
sum (tobgp30_noZero$ncases)
```

However, this gave me the sum of ncases for these tobgp subgroups, but that takes into account all the other variables such as 'agegp' (age groups) and 'alcgp' (daily alcohol consumption).

Comment: Did you mean to say in your last sentence that calculating the percentage of cases by group _doesn't_ take into account other variables such as age and alcohol consumption?

Comment: *I'm interested in knowing for each groups, what is the percentage of ncases ?* ... what groups: `agegp`, `alcgp`, `tobgp`? And `ncases` percentage out of what total?

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to correctly calculate the sum of `ncases` by group. To turn this into the percent of all cases, you just divide by the total number of cases across all groups (which is 200 in this case).

I find that generating calculations by group is much easier with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

X %>% 
  mutate(ncases_total = sum(ncases)) %>% 
  group_by(tobgp) %>% 
  summarise(ncases_sum = sum(ncases),
            ncases_total = first(ncases_total),
            ncases_pct = 100 * (ncases_sum / ncases_total)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, there is one thing I don't get, on the graph with the code that I have showed, for example for the tobgp group 0-9, it shows an average number of cases of something higher than 3. However, when we look at the number of cases for this group, we have 78 ncases... How is the discrepency explained ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a combination of `aggregate` and `ave`:

```
agg_df <- aggregate(ncases ~ tobgp, esoph, sum)   
agg_df$pct <- with(agg_df, ave(ncases, tobgp, FUN=sum) / sum(ncases))

agg_df
#      tobgp ncases   pct
# 1 0-9g/day     78 0.390
# 2    10-19     58 0.290
# 3    20-29     33 0.165
# 4      30+     31 0.155
```

Alternatively, all in one line using `within`:

```
agg_df <- within(aggregate(ncases ~ tobgp, esoph, sum),
                  pct <- ave(ncases, tobgp, FUN=sum) / sum(ncases))

agg_df
#      tobgp ncases   pct
# 1 0-9g/day     78 0.390
# 2    10-19     58 0.290
# 3    20-29     33 0.165
# 4      30+     31 0.155
```

Same can be handled across the other groupings

```
within(aggregate(ncases ~ agegp, esoph, sum),
       pct <- ave(ncases, agegp, FUN=sum) / sum(ncases))

#   agegp ncases   pct
# 1 25-34      1 0.005
# 2 35-44      9 0.045
# 3 45-54     46 0.230
# 4 55-64     76 0.380
# 5 65-74     55 0.275
# 6   75+     13 0.065

within(aggregate(ncases ~ alcgp, esoph, sum),
       pct <- ave(ncases, alcgp, FUN=sum) / sum(ncases))

#       alcgp ncases   pct
# 1 0-39g/day     29 0.145
# 2     40-79     75 0.375
# 3    80-119     51 0.255
# 4      120+     45 0.225
```

Even multiple groupings:

```
agg_df <- within(aggregate(ncases ~ agegp + alcgp + tobgp, esoph, sum),
                 pct <- ave(ncases, agegp, alcgp, tobgp, FUN=sum) / sum(ncases))

head(agg_df)
#   agegp     alcgp    tobgp ncases   pct
# 1 25-34 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      0 0.000
# 2 35-44 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      0 0.000
# 3 45-54 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      1 0.005
# 4 55-64 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      2 0.010
# 5 65-74 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      5 0.025
# 6   75+ 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      1 0.005

tail(agg_df)
#    agegp  alcgp tobgp ncases   pct
# 83 55-64 80-119   30+      4 0.020
# 84 65-74 80-119   30+      1 0.005
# 85 25-34   120+   30+      0 0.000
# 86 45-54   120+   30+      4 0.020
# 87 55-64   120+   30+      5 0.025
# 88 65-74   120+   30+      1 0.005
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, there is one thing I don't get, on the graph with the code that I have showed, for example for the tobgp group 0-9, it shows an average number of cases of something higher than 3. However, when we look at the number of cases for this group, we have 78 ncases... How is the discrepency explained ?

Comment: I do not run *mean* number of cases but *total* number of cases by grouping. Percentages usually run off of grouping totals out of all.